# toggleClass not working on my Vscode compared to YouTube video

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code on toggle is not working as on the Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDbjsABOnAU) I am watching, toggleClass is not working.

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-times');
        $('header').toggleClass('toggle');
    });

    $(window).on('scroll load', function() {

        $('#menu').removeClass('fa-times');
        $('header').removeClass('toggle');
    });
});
```

Here is my scss:

```
@media (max-width:991px) {
    header {
        left:-120%;

        .toggle {
            left:0%;
        }
    }

    #menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Here is the git link for the full code: https://github.com/genius101/FrontEnd_Projs/tree/main/site/v2

Would look to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `&` before `.toggle`

```
@media (max-width:991px) {
header {
    left:-120%;

    &.toggle {
        left:0%;
    }
}

#menu {
    display: block;
}
```

}